# How to send list of items to function in new thread using python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want send list of items to function in new thread:

```
thread = Thread(target=commit_list, args=(list))
thread.start()

def commit_list(list):
    for p in list:
        print p
```

In this code, I am getting error:

> TypeError: commit_list() takes exactly 1 argument (11 given)

I dont know why.

I tried:
Compile error:

```
Thread(target=commit_list, args=(*list))
```

and
Compile error:

```
Thread(target=commit_list, args=(**list))
```

and
Same error with 11 given arguments

```
Thread(target=commit_list, args=(list[:]))
```

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `args=(list,)` instead.

since args needs to be a tuple, `(list)` will just be a list, but `(list,)` will be a tuple including a list as the first argument.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @chaphouk np :)